# Process.Start enforces additional memory constraints on a process?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have written a PowerShell cmdlet, which takes away some memory.

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Size * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

It works fine, if it runs in a PowerShell prompt directly.

However, if I try to start a process of PowerShell in C# and run it, it throws an OutOfMemoryException.

```
Process.Start("PowerShell", @"-NoExit -Command ""Import-Module Something.dll; Take-Memory -Size 1000;""");
```

Does Process.Start enforce additional memory constraints on a process? How can I work around with this?

Edit:

Using Run with

```
PowerShell -NoExit -Command "Import-Module Something.dll; Take-Memory -Size 1000;"
```

also works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, I try an answer here because it's too long for a comment :

**Hypothesis :**

Your are using a 64 bits OS (Seven, Windows 8 ...)

When you run PowerShell command line or run PowerShell at the command line, by default you run 64 bits PowerShell.

When you compile your C# program, you don't take care of the fact that you target a 32 bits executable. So your EXE by default invoke a 32 bits PowerShell exe. In my opinion 1Go is too big to be found in one piece in a 32 bits PowerShell EXE.

**Conclusion :**

Can you try to target 64 bits for your C# EXE program ?